# SVG shadow не появляется

Tags: css, css3, svg, svg-filter

SVG, с которым я работаю, имеет тень, сделанную с помощью фильтра `feGaussianBlur`.

Сама тень по бокам  отображается правильно, но  сверху и снизу обрезается.

Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код этой картинки:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg
  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'
  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<svg height="600" version="1.1" width="700" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs/>
  <filter id="SVGID_0">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="6.6"/>
    <feOffset dx="0" dy="0"/>
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode/>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <path d="M 0 83 Q 0 83 0 83 Q 0 83 6 79.5 Q 12 76 17 71 Q 22 66 30.5 57.5 Q 39 49 54 36 Q 69 23 82.5 16.5 Q 96 10 120 4.5 Q 144 -1 170.5 0 Q 197 1 218 16.5 Q 239 32 253.5 51 Q 268 70 278 83.5 Q 288 97 299 110 Q 310 123 320 129.5 Q 330 136 338 136.5 Q 346 137 355 129.5 L 364 122" stroke-linecap="round" style="stroke: #005e7a; stroke-width: 30; fill: none; filter: url(#SVGID_0);" transform="translate(50 50)" />
</svg>
```

Почему тень обрезается только по вертикали, а горизонтально не обрезается?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG shadow cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17883655/7394871) от участника  [@kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax).</sub>

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17883655/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно увеличить размер `filter region`

`<filter id="SVGID_0" y="-40%" height="180%">`

Работает просто отлично.

Значения по умолчанию для области фильтра: `x = "- 10%"` `y = "- 10%"` `width = "120%"` `height = "120%"` - большие  размеры размытия обычно обрезаются..

(Ваша тень не обрезается горизонтально, потому что  ширина вашей фигуры составляет около 2,5x от вашей высоты, так что дополнительных 10% региона действия фильтра попадают в эту область вашей фигуры)

Кроме того, область y-фильтра, по-видимому, вычисляется так, как если бы `path` имел `stroke` с нулевым пикселем, поэтому фильтр игнорирует ширину `stroke`.

(У разных браузеров разное поведение зависит от того, считают ли они, что `stroke` является частью `bounding box` для расчета области фильтра).

Обратите внимание, что если ваша конкретная форма равна либо нулевой ширине, либо нулевой высоте (например, горизонтальной или вертикальной линии), то тогда вы должны указать `filterUnits = "userSpaceOnUse"`, как часть объявления фильтра и явно укажите область фильтра (x, y, width, height).  `userSpaceUnits` (обычно в пикселях) для  создания достаточного пространства для отображения тени.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg
  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'
  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<svg height="600" version="1.1" width="700" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs/>
  <filter id="SVGID_0"  y="-40%" height="180%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="6.6"/>
    <feOffset dx="0" dy="0"/>
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode/>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <path d="M 0 83 Q 0 83 0 83 Q 0 83 6 79.5 Q 12 76 17 71 Q 22 66 30.5 57.5 Q 39 49 54 36 Q 69 23 82.5 16.5 Q 96 10 120 4.5 Q 144 -1 170.5 0 Q 197 1 218 16.5 Q 239 32 253.5 51 Q 268 70 278 83.5 Q 288 97 299 110 Q 310 123 320 129.5 Q 330 136 338 136.5 Q 346 137 355 129.5 L 364 122" stroke-linecap="round" style="stroke: #005e7a; stroke-width: 30; fill: none; filter: url(#SVGID_0);" transform="translate(50 50)" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [SVG shadow cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17891104/7394871) от участника  [@Michael Mullany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271353/michael-mullany).</sub>